# How add to cart in magento works?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

**How add to cart in magento works ?**

As is it based on the session

OR

```
We can add the product to cart to a particular user using external php call



 require_once '../app/Mage.php'; 
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); 
    umask(0);  
    Mage::app();  
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(99);  // Random product ID

    // get cart and add product
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, 1);

    // update session
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    // save the cart
    $cart->save();
```

As the above `code not using any session and customer id am in a bit of confusion , and i called this externally` . i asked this question because i first call this via `poster` , and `when i logged in to the site the product is not there in cart for that`user  .

Answer (score 3):

If you need to work on the **most recent active cart** of a *specific customer* I suggest you to use the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::loadByCustomer()` method.

Here is a sample code which assumes you are in a fully initialized Magento frontend application:

```
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(<customer_id>);

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
if (!$quote->getId()) {
    $quote
        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->setCustomer($customer)
        ->save();
}
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<saleable_product_id>);

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $quoteItem */
$quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, /* qty = */ 1)->save();

$quote->save();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you give a sample of how to use it

Comment: and this is retrieval right  , but how to set cart for a customer ,

Comment: When i used it like :- $cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($userId);
print_r($cart);exit(); it wont print any

Comment: I edited my answer and added sample code; hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the script it uses a Magento user session based on a cookie `frontend` to add the product to a particular cart tied to a session.

Since the script is probably called by a server or something like that it's not linked to your browsers session. In case this script works as it should calling it via your browser should add it to a cart that links to your browsers Magento session